# Most efficient way to fix an invalid JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, .net-4.0, fastjson

I am stuck in an impossible situation. I have a JSON from outer space (there is no way they are going to change it). Here is the JSON

```
{
    user:'180111',
    title:'I\'m sure "E pluribus unum" means \'Out of Many, One.\' \n\nhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_pluribus_unum.\n\n\'',
    date:'2007/01/10 19:48:38',
    "id":"3322121",
    "previd":112211,
    "body":"\'You\' can \"read\" more here [url=http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/?search=E_pluribus_unum]E pluribus unum[\/url]'s. Cheers \\*/ :\/",
    "from":"112221",
    "username":"mikethunder",
    "creationdate":"2007\/01\/10 14:04:49"
}
```

*"It is nowhere near a valid JSON"*,I said. And their response was *"emmm! but Javascript can read it without complain"*:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = {"PUT JSON FROM UP THERE HERE"};

    document.write(obj.title);
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write(obj.creationdate + " " + obj.date);
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write(obj.body);
    document.write("<br />");
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Problem**

I am supposed to read and parse this string via .NET(4) and it broke 3 out of 14 library mentioned in C# section of [Json.org](http://json.org) (didn't try rest of them). To make the problem go away, I wrote following function to fix the issue with single and double quotes.

```
public static string JSONBeautify(string InStr){
    bool inSingleQuote = false;
    bool inDoubleQuote = false;
    bool escaped = false;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(InStr);
    sb = sb.Replace("`", "<°)))><"); // replace all instances of "grave accent" to "fish" so we can use that mark later. 
                                        // Hopefully there is no "fish" in our JSON
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++) {
        switch (sb[i]) {

            case '\\':
                if (!escaped)
                    escaped = true;
                else 
                    escaped = false;
                break;
            case '\'':
                if (!inSingleQuote && !inDoubleQuote) {
                    sb[i] = '"';            // Change opening single quote string markers to double qoute
                    inSingleQuote = true;
                } else if (inSingleQuote && !escaped) {
                    sb[i] = '"';            // Change closing single quote string markers to double qoute
                    inSingleQuote = false;
                } else if (escaped) {
                    escaped = false;
                }
                break;
            case '"':
                if (!inSingleQuote && !inDoubleQuote) {
                    inDoubleQuote = true;   // This is a opening double quote string marker
                } else if (inSingleQuote && !escaped) {
                    sb[i] = '`';            // Change unescaped double qoute to grave accent
                } else if (inDoubleQuote && !escaped) {
                    inDoubleQuote = false; // This is a closing double quote string marker
                } else if (escaped) {
                    escaped = false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                escaped = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString()
        .Replace("\\/", "/")        // Remove all instances of escaped / (\/) .hopefully no smileys in string
        .Replace("`", "\\\"")       // Change all "grave accent"s to escaped double quote \"
        .Replace("<°)))><", "`")   // change all fishes back to "grave accent"
        .Replace("\\'","'");        // change all escaped single quotes to just single quote
}
```

Now JSONlint only complains about attribute names and I can use both JSON.NET and SimpleJSON libraries to parse above JSON.

**Question**

I am sure my code is not the best way of fixing mentioned JSON.
Is there any scenario that my code might break? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: That JSON is so wrong on so many levels. However we can fix it.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but as they are from outer space, they don't speak our language and making them understand it is wrong is ... well impossible.

Comment: If you need a library to do it, you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonrepair otherwise you can also try https://ray.run/tools/json-repairer

Comment: @LucGagan, for something as simple as 3 lines of code in Bistro's answer, I don't think you will need a library. BTW  that was a one time data migration and completed 8 years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run this through JavaScript. Fire up a JavaScript parser in *.net*. Give the string as input to JavaScript and use JavaScript's native `JSON.stringify` to convert:

```js
obj = {
    "user":'180111',
    "title":'I\'m sure "E pluribus unum" means \'Out of Many, One.\' \n\nhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_pluribus_unum.\n\n',
    "date":'2007/01/10 19:48:38',
    "id":"3322121",
    "previd":"112211",
    "body":"\'You\' can \"read\" more here [url=http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/?search=E_pluribus_unum]E pluribus unum[\/url]'s. Cheers \\*/ :\/",
    "from":"112221",
    "username":"mikethunder",
    "creationdate":"2007\/01\/10 14:04:49"
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Please remember that the string (or rather object) you've got isn't valid JSON and can't be parsed with a JSON library. It needs to be converted to valid JSON first. However it's valid JavaScript.

To complete this answer: You can use `JavaScriptSerializer` in *.Net*. For this solution you'll need the following assemblies:

- System.Net
- System.Web.Script.Serialization

  ```
  var webClient = new WebClient();
  string readHtml = webClient.DownloadString("uri to your source (extraterrestrial)");
  var a = new JavaScriptSerializer();

  Dictionary<string, object> results = a.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(readHtml);
  ```

Comment: Great answer. If you want to go all the way, include an example or a list of .Net json parsers (maybe even just using the simple WebBrowser?). Neat trick with the js snippets in the answer, me likey.

Comment: It is a good idea to give the job to someone who knows how to do it, however any suggestion on how I run a Javascript parser in .net? Does `Javascript.NET` or `Jint` handle this java object properly?

Comment: @BobSort, take a look at the updated answer. This will parse the horrible JSONish object and spit out a nice *.Net* Dictionary list. I tried it with your source and it worked.

Comment: Nice job with both part of your answer. specially I like the inline run snippet. by the way, your second part of code does not handle all type of JSON such as arrays `[...]`

Comment: Well I can't use Dictionary, the JSON mentioned above is part of a bigger object array. However if I use object instead of Dictionary I can get results.

Comment: Well the dictionary is an example. Reading your comment I guess you're back on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
 string AlienJSON = "your alien JSON";
 JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 string ProperJSON = js.Serialize(js.DeserializeObject(AlienJSON));
```

Or just consume the object after deserialize instead of converting it back to string and passing it to a JSON parser for extra headache

As Mouser also mentioned you need to use [System.Web.Script.Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is available by including [system.web.extensions.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520569/where-can-i-find-the-assembly-system-web-extensions-dll) in your project and to do that you need to change Target framework in project properties to `.NET Framework 4`.

**EDIT**

Trick to consume deserialized object is using `dynamic`

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic obj = js.DeserializeObject(AlienJSON);
```

for JSON in your question simply use

```
string body = obj["body"];
```

or if your JSON is an array

```
if (obj is Array) {
    foreach(dynamic o in obj){
        string body = obj[0]["body"];
        // ... do something with it
    }
}
```

Comment: How I can consume the object after deserialize?

Comment: Have you tried to put the JavaScript string inside a .Net string? It will not work. You need to load it externally. Hence the webclient.

Answer (score 0):

here's a function I made that will fix broken json:

```
function fixJSON(json){
    function bulkRegex(str, callback){
        if(callback && typeof callback === 'function'){
            return callback(str);
        }else if(callback && Array.isArray(callback)){
            for(let i = 0; i < callback.length; i++){
                if(callback[i] && typeof callback[i] === 'function'){
                    str = callback[i](str);
                }else{break;}
            }
            return str;
        }
        return str;
    }
    if(json && json !== ''){
        if(typeof json !== 'string'){
            try{
                json = JSON.stringify(json);
            }catch(e){return false;}
        }
        if(typeof json === 'string'){
            json = bulkRegex(json, false, [
                str => str.replace(/[\n\t]/gm, ''),
                str => str.replace(/,\}/gm, '}'),
                str => str.replace(/,\]/gm, ']'),
                str => {
                    str = str.split(/(?=[,\}\]])/g);
                    str = str.map(s => {
                        if(s.includes(':') && s){
                            let strP = s.split(/:(.+)/, 2);
                            strP[0] = strP[0].trim();
                            if(strP[0]){
                                let firstP = strP[0].split(/([,\{\[])/g);
                                firstP[firstP.length-1] = bulkRegex(firstP[firstP.length-1], false, p => p.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_]/, ''));
                                strP[0] = firstP.join('');
                            }
                            let part = strP[1].trim();
                            if((part.startsWith('"') && part.endsWith('"')) || (part.startsWith('\'') && part.endsWith('\'')) || (part.startsWith('`') && part.endsWith('`'))){
                                part = part.substr(1, part.length - 2);
                            }
                            part = bulkRegex(part, false, [
                                p => p.replace(/(["])/gm, '\\$1'),
                                p => p.replace(/\\'/gm, '\''),
                                p => p.replace(/\\`/gm, '`'),
                            ]);
                            strP[1] = ('"'+part+'"').trim();
                            s = strP.join(':');
                        }
                        return s;
                    });
                    return str.join('');
                },
                str => str.replace(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2":'),
                str => {
                    str = str.split(/(?=[,\}\]])/g);
                    str = str.map(s => {
                        if(s.includes(':') && s){
                            let strP = s.split(/:(.+)/, 2);
                            strP[0] = strP[0].trim();
                            if(strP[1].includes('"') && strP[1].includes(':')){
                                let part = strP[1].trim();
                                if(part.startsWith('"') && part.endsWith('"')){
                                    part = part.substr(1, part.length - 2);
                                    part = bulkRegex(part, false, p => p.replace(/(?<!\\)"/gm, ''));
                                }
                                strP[1] = ('"'+part+'"').trim();
                            }
                            s = strP.join(':');
                        }
                        return s;
                    });
                    return str.join('');
                },
            ]);
            try{
                json = JSON.parse(json);
            }catch(e){return false;}
        }
        return json;
    }
    return false;
}
```