# The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Could someone help me figure this out? Up until now, my project has been going fine as I added references. Then I needed System.Web.Extensions, which is shown as being checked in my Reference Manager, but is causing the error in the title of this thread.

Screenshot proofs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520569/where-can-i-find-the-assembly-system-web-extensions-dll

Comment: Could it be you are Targeting .net 4.5 and this namespace is in .net 4.0 it is obselete in .net 4.5 see here for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419161%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Habib In picture, I think OP _already_ found this dll? :)

Comment: Is this the same project you were having reference problems with [last week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111243/am-i-missing-a-reference-is-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-binder-not-defined)?