# can not add System.Web.Extensions Assembly as reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I need to use **System.Web.Script.Serialization** which is located at **System.Web.Extensions** assembly. but in my vs 13 environment reference>assembly>framework the System.Web.Extensions is not showing. what is my project missing?

Comment: Reference....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520569/where-can-i-find-the-assembly-system-web-extensions-dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these step by step

1. Right Click you project Select Properties
2. Change your Target Framework to ".NET Framework 4"
3. Do whatever you need to do to save the changes and close the preferences tab
4. Right click on the References item in your Solution Explorer
5. Choose Add Reference...
6. In the .NET tab, scroll down to System.Web.Extensions and add it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get from this location

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Extensions.dll
```

Reference

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520569/where-can-i-find-the-assembly-system-web-extensions-dll
```