# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to develop a web application that displays some charts based on different data that is stored in a database. I found on different tutorials online that I should transfer the data from the controller to the view using a model and then to use Json.Encode for the data to be read correctly by my chart.
First it didn't recognize Json.Encode method, so I had to use NuGet Packet Manager to install Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages and when I try to run the app, this error pops up.

I am using .NET Core 5.0

This is where the error comes in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart = document.getElementById('pie').getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(chart, {
    type: 'pie',
    data : @Html.Raw(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(Model.PieChartData)),
});
</script>
```

This is how I build the model that is given to the view:

```
public PieChartVM GetPieChartData()
    {
        var model = new PieChartVM();

        var labels = new List<string>();
        labels.Add("Green");
        labels.Add("Blue");
        labels.Add("Gray");
        labels.Add("Purple");

        model.labels = labels;

        var dataset = new List<PieChartChildVM>();
        var childModel = new PieChartChildVM();

        var backgroundColorList = new List<string>();
        var dataList = new List<int>();

        foreach(var label in labels)
        {
            if (label == "Green")
            {
                backgroundColorList.Add("#2ecc71");
                dataList.Add(12);
            }
            if (label == "Blue")
            {
                backgroundColorList.Add("#3498db");
                dataList.Add(20);
            }
            if (label == "Gray")
            {
                backgroundColorList.Add("#95a5a6");
                dataList.Add(18);
            }
            if (label == "Purple")
            {
                backgroundColorList.Add("#9b59b6");
                dataList.Add(50);
            }
        }

        childModel.backgroundColor = backgroundColorList;
        childModel.data = dataList;
        dataset.Add(childModel);
        model.datasets = dataset;

        return model;
    }
```

Comment: Try uninstalling that package "Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages", and use JSON.stringify() instead of System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(). I believe what you are trying to use is only available in .Net Framework and not .Net Core. Here is a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220168/can-not-add-system-web-extensions-assembly-as-reference/51220239

Comment: @jelde015 thanks for your answer. I tried that but now instead of an error, it doesn't display the chart like the dataset is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourModel);
```

OR

```
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    var jsonModel = serializer.Serialize(YOURMODEL);
```

Comment: the second method is no good for my program, as System.Web.Script requires System.Web.Extensions. And for the first one, I tried pulling jsonString using HTML data-attribute or ajax calls but still the chart won't display anything...