# Net Core 2.2 / NetStandard 2.0 Error System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Extensions

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm creating a *Netcore 2.2* API and I need to use an assembly of a provider to connect its systems.
When I run my tests, the result is:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

The problem is when I create an instance of a class of the references assembly.

How could create a net core or netstandard project that works with that assembly? 
It works with a Net 4.8 framework project.

Comment: `System.Web.Extensions` is part of full .NET framework. What would you like to use from this assembly?

Comment: I don't know. I referenced an assembly and this one has a dependency with System.Web.Extensions. I can't access to the code of the assembly, so looking for a workaround or something that let me to create an net core API to use that assembly.

Comment: @dcanamares what assembly did you reference? That's not a .NET Standard assembly and the version number is *very old*.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I got a solution. I found the assembly in the GAC (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35), copied to local folder in the project and added the reference to this file and It works.

Comment: .NET Standard 2.0 assemblies are *not* stored in the GAC. Only .NET Old assemblies are stored there. The version number shows it's an *old* version too. 3.5 refers to the .NET version issued with Windows Vista. It would have issues running on a .NET 4.0 runtime. On .NET Core, you're on your own

Comment: In any case, .NET Framework assemblies can be found in the SDK folder. [This is explained in this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520569/where-can-i-find-the-assembly-system-web-extensions-dll)